# Async and DB Calls

Tags: sql, asynchronous, spring-data-jpa, proxy

I am fetching View data based on the filters that are given as an input from Oracle SQL DB using spring data JPA, It is taking around 5mins using Async annotation and without async annotation it is taking around 2mins, My server throws 502 error if the response time of API is more than 1 min to overcome this issue I need to use Async annotation, how can I reduce the DB retrieval time. for my case, I am retrieving around 1300 records.

I am using indexing to the columns of the tables that the view is using even though I am getting output in around 5 mins